# Dynamical radio button group validation

Tags: javascript, php

sample javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName("co[]");
    for (var i = 0; i < radiobutton.length; i++) {
        if (radiobutton[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    alert("At least one radio button has not been selected");
    return false;
}
```

Sample php :

```
<form method="post" action="result.php" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<?php   
    $_SESSION['two']=$_POST;

    $query1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM option WHERE code IN("'.implode('","',$_POST['co']).'")'); 
    while($data1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
    {               
        echo $data1['name'];                                    
?>          
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Detail</td>
            <td>Select</td>
        </tr>
    <?php                       
        $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM detailoption WHERE code="'.$data1['code'].'"');
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {           
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$data['detail']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='radio' value='".$data['detail']."' name='co[".$data['code']."]' /></td>";
            echo "</tr>";               
        }                       
    ?>
    </table>
<?php
    }
?>              
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

when I select the radio button and submit, the system displays an error message.
when I don't select the radio button and submit, the system also displays an error message.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your line `var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName("co[]");` always return empty array because you don't have any input with that name.

You should store your `code` information in the `value` attributes of the input, and if you want to retrieve the `detail` field in the result, you should store the `detailoption_id` in the `value` attributes, because all your rows in the table have the same code, but may be not the same detail.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM detailoption WHERE code="'.$data1['code'].'"');
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {           
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$data['detail']."</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='radio' value='".$data['code']."' name='co' /></td>";
            echo "</tr>";               
        }
```

and then get your inputs list from the new name given

`var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName("co");`

Answer (score 0):

> first give a name to form -like myform and try this. i hope it will be used for you.

```
function validateForm()    {

len = document.myform.co.length

for (i = 0; i <len; i++)
{
   if (document.myform.co[i].checked) 
   {
     return true;
   }

   alert("At least one radio button has not been selected");
   return false;
}
```